# Is it bad practice to calculate within the insert query?

Tags: postgresql, computed-column

I am trying to do a web application for time sheets.

I have three options to calculate the value of hours (AFAIK):

1. In the form
2. In the backend
3. In the query

Is it smart or bad practice to do this calculation in the SQL query?

```
with list as (select code_id,code_ppu from code)

insert into hr values
(default,'JD','20-0001','PM','testing',1.25,
(select code_ppu from list where code_id='PM'),
(select 1.25 * code_ppu from list where code_id='PM')),
 
(default,'JD','20-0001','COPY','testing',2.25,
(select code_ppu from list where code_id='COPY'),
(select 2.25 * code_ppu from list where code_id='COPY'));
```

db fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f8nZn5LQfbmKxAdxX2fdej/50

Answer (score 1):

```sql
INSERT INTO hr (hr_sign, hr_job, hr_code, hr_subject, hr_qty, hr_ppu, hr_sum)
SELECT 'JD',
       '20-0001',
       code_id,
       'testing',
       CASE code_id WHEN 'PM' THEN 1.25
                    WHEN 'COPY' THEN 2.25
                    END, 
       code_ppu, 
       code_ppu * CASE code_id WHEN 'PM' THEN 1.25
                               WHEN 'COPY' THEN 2.25
                               END
FROM code
WHERE code_id IN ('PM','COPY');
```

PS. It is safe to store the relation between `code_id` and according coefficient (set into `hr_qty` and used during `hr_sum` calculation) in separate table and use this table in data source instead of `CASE`s.

---

> Is it smart or bad practice to do this calculation in the SQL query?

Calculations is a norma. But shown subqueries usage - hardly...

---

> How do I transfer them as parameters?

For example, something like (not tested)

```sql
INSERT INTO hr (hr_sign, hr_job, hr_code, hr_subject, hr_qty, hr_ppu, hr_sum)
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT one_row
          FROM REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(@packed_csv, ',') AS parameters(one_row) ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT SPLIT_PART(one_row, ':', 1) AS code_id,
                 SPLIT_PART(one_row, ':', 2)::DECIMAL AS multiplier 
          FROM cte1 )
SELECT 'JD',
       '20-0001',
       code.code_id,
       'testing',
       cte2.multiplier, 
       code.code_ppu, 
       code.code_ppu * cte2.multiplier
FROM code
JOIN cte2 ON code.code_id = cte2.code_id;
```

where `@packed_csv` is a string like `'PM:1.25,COPY:2.25'`,

Comment: And when the codes are unknown (custom)? The cases can be 100 options...

Comment: @sibert Save it into temporary table (or build such table as a rowset in CTE - transfer as a parameter, where the codes are packed into one CSV, for example, and unnest) and use.

Comment: I used CTE in my example. How do I transfer them as parameters?

Comment: @sibert Updated, please test.

Comment: I think WITH must be created before INSERT INTO (like my example). Correct me if I am wrong. How do you transfer parameters then?

Comment: @sibert *I think WITH must be created before INSERT INTO* These are syntactic details... *How do you transfer parameters then?* How do YOU transfer parameters to queries in YOUR programming language/tool? `@packed_csv` shows where the parameter value must be transferrred to (the place where you must type/posess the parameter placeholder).